# Following getting started video. Not getting started

Tags: jhipster

This should be an easy one. I'm going through the 20 minute video
http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/

and hit this error at this point: https://youtu.be/ZGF4gEM4FuA?t=338

Ideas?

```
// ♥ gradlew bootrun
:compileJava
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/config/DatabaseConfiguration.java:19: error: package org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config does not exist
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
                                                               ^
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/config/DatabaseConfiguration.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.berniesanders.bernierebuttals.repository.search")
 ^
  symbol: class EnableElasticsearchRepositories
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/domain/User.java:8: error: package org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations does not exist
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
                                                         ^
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/domain/User.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@Document(indexName="user")
 ^
  symbol: class Document
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/repository/search/UserSearchRepository.java:4: error: package org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository does not exist
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
                                                        ^
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/repository/search/UserSearchRepository.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public interface UserSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Long> {
                                              ^
  symbol: class ElasticsearchRepository
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/web/rest/UserResource.java:23: error: package org.elasticsearch.index.query does not exist
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;
                                           ^
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/service/UserService.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
                userSearchRepository.save(user);
                                    ^
  symbol:   method save(User)
  location: variable userSearchRepository of type UserSearchRepository
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/service/UserService.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        userSearchRepository.save(newUser);
                            ^
  symbol:   method save(User)
  location: variable userSearchRepository of type UserSearchRepository
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/service/UserService.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
            userSearchRepository.save(u);
                                ^
  symbol:   method save(User)
  location: variable userSearchRepository of type UserSearchRepository
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/service/UserService.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
            userSearchRepository.delete(user);
                                ^
  symbol:   method delete(User)
  location: variable userSearchRepository of type UserSearchRepository
/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/src/main/java/com/berniesanders/bernierebuttals/web/rest/UserResource.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            .stream(userSearchRepository.search(queryString(query)).spliterator(), false)
                                                ^
  symbol:   method queryString(String)
  location: class UserResource
12 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.211 secs
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing Elasticsearch as a dependency. You can compare your project with the one from the video at https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-demo. Elasticsearch is included in build.gradle https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-demo/blob/master/build.gradle#L151

Comment: That was it. I wonder why this was left out. Should I create an issue?

Comment: It might be caused by the version of JHipster you're using to create your project. I used the master branch the day that video was created. If you can reproduce, please create an issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new